# How to use a parametric statistical test with R?

Tags: r, logistic, nonparametric

I would like to test the null hypothesis that all coefficients of my categorical variable with 4 Levels are really zero using Wald test & R. I'm new to the R family. And just have some problems to implement that question. My model is `lm(Y ~ X + Z)` where `X` is continuous and `Z` qualitative/categorical with 4 levels.

Example:

So I run `model<-lm(prestige~height(cm)+weight(kg)+education)` where `education` is `yes` or `no`. As I saw, I would continue to with `coef(model)` and afterwarts test the $H_0$ as stated above. Then I would use `linearHypothesis(model,c("height(cm)=weight(kg),"education(yes)=education(no)+1")`

And I would get the following output:
`Linear hypothesis test`

`Hypothesis:`
`height-weight = 0`
`education(yes)-education(no) = 1`

So my question is how to compute Z or in der example education with more than 2 Levels...

Comment: You probably should consider providing some data and a minimal example.

Comment: I dont think a data sample would provide more insights. Its a general question. You can think of any data with that specification. Of course, you can consider the categorical variables as dummies.

Comment: The question is how to Compute a Wald test of the null hypothesis that all coefficients of dummy variables for Z are really zero.

Comment: Granted, but all the same you'll get more (and better) answers if you provide the requested information.

Comment: You are right. I have to think..

Comment: The code is unreadable. Why don't you run the model and apply 'drop1(model, test = 'F')' to get the corresponding partial F test?